# Loading an ant project in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I am mainly a C# guy but I do know a bit of java (its been a few years since I did it and I was doing basic classwork style projects (simple calculators, playing card games, ect...) ). Now i have the task of editing a [GPL project](http://www.elusiva.com/opensource/) and tweak some things to customize it to our use.

The issue I am having is I have never imported other peoples code in java before. This appears to be a ant project however I have never even done a ant project before. I created a "free form project" in NetBeans and added the build xml, it appeared to get all the source folders I need, however when I run the build-common task (init-common works fine) i get:

```
build-common:
E:\Java\JavaRDP1.1\rdpclient\build-common.xml:54: The following error occurred while executing this line:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Java\JavaRDP1.1\rdpclient\${commonxml} (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:268)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:177)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:82)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1397)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1366)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1249)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:281)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:539)
        at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:154)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

It appears to be using the placeholder ${commonxml} instead of the actual file (build-common.xml). What do I need to do to fix my errors, and if I am doing this the totally wrong way and there is a better way than creating a "Free form project" please let me know.

Every tutorial that I have googled have been for creating a new ant project from scratch, I have not been able to find anything helpful on importing a existing project.

EDIT: [Here is a copy](http://pastebin.com/JAxYWbdx) of the build-common.xml file if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to generate a project.properties file and put this in it

```
build.dir=Build
dist.dir=Dist
src.dir=src
commonxml=build.xml
java.log4j11.package=log4j-java1.1
java.getopt.package=gnu-getopt-1.0.11-java\\lib
```

That allowed me to build.

Answer (score 0):

My advise would be to try the [automatic project plugin](http://wiki.netbeans.org/AutomaticProjects) for netbeans which should be available in the plugin update center inside the IDE. Using this plugin netbeans skips its normal build system and instead uses the provided build script directly.

Answer (score -2):

The main source of your problem is Netbeans, it uses Ant as basis for all its tasks. If you want to customize the project you are describing, perhaps a simple text editor and a tutorial is the best choice.

Comment: Wouldn't it make since that if netbeans uses ant for it's projects and this is a ant project they should work well together? Could you point me to a tutorial that would cover the issues i need to do?

Comment: Is not that it wouldn't work well, I meant that if you are working on ANT over netbeans you may not want to give Netbeans the control over you build file. build-common.xml is a file that contains lots of code used to build generic projects. About a tutorial, I think the best one is the official http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html.